# how can i escape a group of special characters in java in one method?

Tags: java, lucene, character

i use lucene search but lucene has a bunch of special characters to escape like:

```
- && || ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : \
```

i am having problem escaping these characters because they are too many and if i use the String.replaceAll() method, i'll just end up having a really long line of code just for escaping the characters. what is the best way to do? thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is also a method called [QueryParser#escape](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_5_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/queryParser/QueryParser.html#escape%28java.lang.String%29), which may be useful:

> Returns a String where those characters that QueryParser expects to be escaped are escaped by a preceding \.

Comment: yes. it works and i just reduced and saved lines of codes. Thanks A Lot!

Answer (score 2):

Use regular expression to replace those characters in one go.

example:

```
 String s="some text && || []!{} ()^*?~ and ";
        Pattern p= Pattern.compile("([-&\\|!\\(\\){}\\[\\]\\^\"\\~\\*\\?:\\\\])");

        s=p.matcher(s).replaceAll("\\\\$1");
        System.out.println(s);\\prints some text \&\& \|\| \[\]\!\{\} \(\)\^\*\?\~ and
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expression. `String.replaceAll()` supports regular expression, so you can solve this problem using one single call. Just be careful: some of these characters are special for regular expressions too, so they mus be escaped "twice":

`str.replaceAll("([-\\&\\|!\\(\\)\\{\\}\\[\\]\\^\\"~\\*\\?:\\])", "\\$1");`

(I have not tried this, probably this line needs some fixes, but this is the idea)

Answer (score -1):

There is a Apache Commons Library for that:
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html