# Java method to escape characters + - & | ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : \ / =

Tags: java, lucene

Can anyone recommend a standard Java method which will escape All of the characters listed below, or am I best to write my own method to do this?

```
From:   + - & | ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : \ / =

To:     \+ \- \& \| \! \( \) \{ \} \[ \] \^ \" \~ \* \? \: \\ \/ \=
```

The reason I need this is because I need to create and comply with Lucene Queries as defined here:

https://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html

https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/jackrabbit/oak/trunk/oak-lucene/src/main/java/org/apache/jackrabbit/oak/plugins/index/lucene/LucenePropertyIndex.java

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9323848/how-can-i-escape-a-group-of-special-characters-in-java-in-one-method#9323938

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've got one easy way. I used ctrl+C and ctrl+V, since they were already there:

```
Set<Character> repl = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList('+', '-', '&', '|', '!', '(', ')',
                 '{', '}', '[', ']', '^', '"', '~', '*', '?', ':', '\\', '/', '='));

public String escape(String in) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(in);
    for (int i = 0; i < sb.length(); i++) {
        if (repl.contains(sb.charAt(i))) {
            sb.insert(i, '\\');
            i++; //skip our backslash
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

No messy regex, and only a single iteration through the input string.

Outside of that, you could consider `Matcher#quoteReplacement` but I don't believe it covers all the characters you want.